How can I trigger workflow defined in GitHub app?
I'm building a GitHub app which can be integrated into few repos.
Is it possible to define a workflow which is somehow stored on GitHub app side, but is triggered automatically on push of integrator repo?
Reason is just simplicity for integrators, I don't want to force them to modify their workflows.
